# Angular 2 api data

Tags: json, angular, api

I want to get data from Riot API and display it in html view. 
However, i can not "hold" this data in my variable. Console log show empty array.
I can see json data only in function scope. 
I guess, i didn`t use observable function corretly, am i wrong?
Here is my component.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FRIEND } from '../../services/_friends/mock-friends';
import { APIKEY } from '../../services/_lolapi/apikey';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { KeysPipe } from '../../pipes/key';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-friends',
  templateUrl: './friends.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./friends.component.css']
})
export class FriendsComponent implements OnInit {
friends = FRIEND;
apikey = APIKEY;
nick: string[];
query: string;

  private apiUrl =
  'https://eun1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/';
  data: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(private http: Http) {



   }

getFriendData(query) {

return this.http.get(query)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json());

}
getContacts() {
  this.getFriendData(this.query).subscribe(data => {

    this.data = data;
    console.log(this.data);

  });
}


  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i of this.friends) {
        this.query = `${this.apiUrl}${i.nick}${this.apikey}`;
  this.getFriendData(this.query);
   this.getContacts();
console.log(i.nick);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You never subscribe to the observable returned from your `getFriendData` method, therefore the http request never runs. This is called a cold observable. You have to subscribe to fire the api request. Here is an [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html) on hot vs cold observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `this.getFriendData(this.query)` in `ngOnInit` as in the next line you call `getContacts` that wraps `getFriendData`.

Now, your API returns SummonerDTO - a complex object and you are trying to store it as an Array? That doesn't seem right.
Additionally, it think you want to store every result in an array, right?
In that case you should rather use:

```
this.data.push(data);
```

Comment: It`s working! Big thanks for your advice. I cleaned my mess with functions, as you said. And of course, pushed data into array just work.